# JavaScript array filter not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like this:

```js
var arrayd = [{
        "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
        "CATEGORY": "a",
      },
      {
        "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
        "CATEGORY": "b",
      },
      {
        "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
        "CATEGORY": "c",
      },
      {
        "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
        "CATEGORY": "d",
      },
      {
        "CATEGORY_ID": "3",
        "CATEGORY": "e",
      },
      {
        "CATEGORY_ID": "18",
        "CATEGORY": "f",
      }
    ];
    
    var searchTerm = 1;
    
    arrayd = arrayd.filter(
      s => parseInt(s.CATEGORY_ID.indexOf(parseInt(searchTerm))) !== -1
    );
    
    console.log(arrayd);
```

What I'm trying to dimis filter this array using a `searchTerm`.

In this scenario, `searchTerm` has value 1 but in the response, element with id `18` is also getting returned.

How to fix this?

Note: `searchTerm` will always be numbers.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/67qkf4vx/)

Comment: [Must read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Don't use `indexOf`, just compare the value itself. If You lookup what `indexOf` does, you'll know why it doesn't work, it's also not a flexible solution for what you trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `18` is containing `1` if you consider as a `string`. As [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) documentation states:

> The indexOf() method returns the index within the calling String object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the search at fromIndex. Returns -1 if the value is not found.

So `indexOf` returned a not `-1` value and that's why you got back that object as well from your array.

Just simply use `===` and `parseInt` as follows:

```js
var arrayd = [{
    "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
    "CATEGORY": "a",
  },
  {
    "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
    "CATEGORY": "b",
  },
  {
    "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
    "CATEGORY": "c",
  },
  {
    "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
    "CATEGORY": "d",
  },
  {
    "CATEGORY_ID": "3",
    "CATEGORY": "e",
  },
  {
    "CATEGORY_ID": "18",
    "CATEGORY": "f",
  }
];

var searchTerm = 1;

arrayd = arrayd.filter(
  s => parseInt(s.CATEGORY_ID) === searchTerm
);

console.log(arrayd);
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `CATEGORY` to a number and check if it's equal to the search term:

```js
const arrayd = [{"CATEGORY_ID":"1","CATEGORY":"a"},{"CATEGORY_ID":"1","CATEGORY":"b"},{"CATEGORY_ID":"1","CATEGORY":"c"},{"CATEGORY_ID":"1","CATEGORY":"d"},{"CATEGORY_ID":"3","CATEGORY":"e"},{"CATEGORY_ID":"18","CATEGORY":"f"}];

const searchTerm = 1;

const result = arrayd.filter(
  s => +s.CATEGORY_ID === searchTerm
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're trying to do that in such a convoluted way but you can easily achieve what you want by using:

```
arrayd = arrayd.filter(
  s => parseInt(s.CATEGORY_ID)===searchTerm
);
```

This will return the 4 results you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
I hope the following answer will help you. It's a callback common function to check with the searchItem.

    var arrayd = [{
        "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
        "CATEGORY": "a",
    },
    {
        "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
        "CATEGORY": "b",
    },
    {
        "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
        "CATEGORY": "c",
    },
    {
        "CATEGORY_ID": "1",
        "CATEGORY": "d",
    },
    {
        "CATEGORY_ID": "3",
        "CATEGORY": "e",
    },
    {
        "CATEGORY_ID": "18",
        "CATEGORY": "f",
    }
    ];
    var searchTerm = 1;

    arrayd = arrayd.filter(s => parseInt(s.CATEGORY_ID) == searchTerm)
    console.log(arrayd);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7mx8yj3z/